# Executing all sql files in a folder with ant script (apply task)

Tags: sql, ant, command-line, sqlplus

I have a problem executing all SQL files in a folder with sqlplus command

I can run one file or first file with this code

```
<apply executable="sqlplus" dir="." parallel="false">
    <!-- <arg value="-S" /> -->
    <arg line="${db.user}/${db.pwd}@'${db.sid}'" />
    <arg value="@${db.run.build.script}" />  this is working, which is for executing one file
    <!-- <arg value="--e source" /> -->
    <srcfile/>
    <fileset dir="..\..\Documents\test\Database\SQL\common\test"
        casesensitive="no" description="take all sql files">
        <patternset>
            <include name="**/*.sql" />
        </patternset> 
     </fileset> 
</apply>
```

; but cannot proceed further with other files

I have tried various options with apply task; but still not succeed; I thought the second file hasn't "@" in the beginning that causes the problem.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The `srcfile` nested element accepts a parameter called `prefix` that might help.  See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first of all: I've never used sqlplus :-)

But based on the post I've seen here: http://www.zorbathegeek.com/161/run-multiple-sqlplus-queries-via-dos-batch-file.html I understood that it's a must to provide `@` as a prefix to path to all the files that should be considered.

I see there multiple options, based on restrictions:

- First check if you can provide in command line multiple of your files like this:

`sqlplus [login details] @C:/<your_path>/<file1>.sql @C:/<your_path>/<file1>.sql`

- depending if it's possible or not, you should later decide if you need to create 1 file containing all the filenames prefixed with `@` (as the example provided in the reffered site) or not

Now how to do the prepending? I think it should be simple, just try to use Ant's parhconvert described: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html

```
<fileset dir="..\..\Documents\test\Database\SQL\common\test" id="sql.files">
      <include name="**/*.sql"/>
    </fileset>

<pathconvert pathsep=" " property="prefixed.sql.files" refid="sql.files">
      <map from="c:/" to="@c:/"/>
    </pathconvert>
```

(where you should replace `c:/` with the string that your file paths start with. Moreover, if you will dump to file, `pathsep=" "` should be probably replaced with `pathsep="\n"` as there might be a need to have one file per line, but this needs test)

then depending on the options of all in one file or all files on cmd line, you:

- either need to dump it to tmp file and run using this tmp file name
  http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html
  In this case, the file should be later deleted
- use property prefixed.sql.files directly in your apply arg value like:
  `<arg value="${prefixed.sql.files}" />`